# How to assert if collection is completed

Tags: testing, postman, assertion, newman

Suppose I have a collection of 4 steps.
I need to add an assertion to return success if  last step is reached, and fail if collection execution have interrupted for some reason.

Comment: is it collection or request ?

Comment: When i say steps, I mean requests.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your 4th request status code, you can do your assertion/your actions.

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

if you want to pass/fail the request manually, you should do,

```
tests["Status code is 200"] = true;  // pass
tests["Status code is 200"] = false;  // fail
```

Comment: It is clear for me. My case is: collection have 4 steps. Something went wrong and collection run interrupted on 3rd step. I need to mark such interruption with fail test.

Comment: Automatically postman will intimate in your console. if you want explicitly mention your test as fail. do 'tests["Status code is 200"] = false; '. still not clear, please share me your response and your assertion case

Comment: I have a collection with 4 requests. On 3rd step something went wrong and assertion does not noticed it as fail test, say service give no responce. I want newman to pass success assertion when collection finished, if execution reaches final step.

Comment: if your code in your test script is not valid, postman will throw as console error, not as assertion failure

Comment: It is clear. I need postman to alert me if last request was not made for some reason.

Comment: alter your 3rd request's test script.